# Listbox select event not firing with UpdatePanel and JQuery enabled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jquery, updatepanel

I have a Listbox with some items stored
and from a textbox's key up event i select my choice

the problem i am facing is that
once i select my choice Listbox1_selectIndexchanged event (which sets my choice to another textbox ) not firing properly, it fires only when i hit some button or some page postback event something...

[i have used JQuery and updatepanel]

Here is my Code

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master"             CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" 
title="Untitled Page" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"  runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppnl" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

            prm.add_endRequest(function() {
            $('select[id$=ListBox1]').filterByText($('input[id$=TextBox1]'), true);
            });
            </script>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="border-right: thin groove; border-top: thin groove; border-left: thin groove; border-bottom: thin groove; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; text-align: center; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">

    <br />

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Type"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="SelectedText"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


    &nbsp;<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="119px" Width="126px">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Peache" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Melon" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Lemon" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Pineapple" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Pomegranate" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Mulberry" Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Apricot" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Cherry" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Blackberry" Value="12"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Refresh" />
    <br />
    </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox, selectSingleMatch) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var select = this;
            var options = [];
            $(select).find('option').each(function() {
                options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
            });
            $(select).data('options', options);
            $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
                var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
                var search = $.trim($(this).val());
                var regex = new RegExp(search,"gi");

                $.each(options, function(i) {
                    var option = options[i];
                    if(option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
                        $(select).append(
                           $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                        );
                    }
                });
                if (selectSingleMatch === true && $(select).children().length === 1) {
                    $(select).children().get(0).selected = true;
                }
            });            
        });
    };

    $(function() {
         $('select[id$=ListBox1]').filterByText($('input[id$=TextBox1]'), true); 
    });

    </script>

    </asp:Content>
```

and in my code behind i have

```
    Protected Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event did fire.

Control properties are loaded during the Page_Load method, and your event will fire after the Page_Load method so your page will not reflect its results. All events will fire after the Page_Load method as per the page life cycle.

Try this:

```
Protected Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Page_Load(sender, e)
End Sub
```

To learn more about the page life cycle check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

**EDIT:**

You also need to bind your listbox to your event:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
```

Comment: yes, ur absolutely right but is there a way to force a page_load when a user selects an item in the listbox (say if user types "ap" in textbox then listbox will contain {apple,pineapple,apricot} so if user selects apricot in that instant i want my listbox textchange event to fire) is it possible

Comment: or is there a way to add mouse event to the listbox

Comment: yes got it working , used mouse event from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195288/how-to-add-double-click-mouse-event-to-listbox

Comment: You can force a page load by adding the property `AutoPostback="true"` to your ListBox. Keep in mind that if you are changing control values via javascript that these values will not persists to your C# controls server side.