# asp:Listbox needs to fire an event OnMouseDoubleClick - ASP.NET Framework 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listbox, asp.net-4.0

The project I am working on is in ASP.NET 4. With 4.5, the regular ListBox has an attribute called `OnMouseDoubleClick`. I was wondering what would be the best way to emulate this functionality using an asp:ListBox in ASP.Net 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link really helped me: [How to add Double Click mouse event to listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195288/how-to-add-double-click-mouse-event-to-listbox) After finding it, I rewrote the C# code in VB.net.

.aspx file:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="hiddenColumns" runat="server" ondblclick="hiddenColumns_DoubleClick()"></asp:ListBox>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hiddenColumns_DoubleClick() {
        document.forms[0].hiddenHidden.value = "doubleclicked"
        document.forms[0].submit()
    }
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenHidden" />
```

.aspx.vb file:

```
If Not Request.Params("hiddenHidden") Is Nothing And Request.Params("hiddenHidden") = "doubleclicked" Then
    'Desired actions here
End If
```