# don't see events (like DoubleClick) in properties of WebControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

this might be a bad installation on my machine but I dont see standard events like (doubleclick, mousedoubleclick ) events in tool box > properties

There is no event firing when I write the code manually .

The screenshot that what I see  for ListBox controller

[image]

Comment: There is no "doubleclick" event for ListBox - why did you expect there to be one? It's not mentioned in the documentation either: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox?view=netframework-4.7.2#events

Comment: hmm, I was following this link which show doubleclick event .. my purpose is to fire event on doubleclick on selected item so copy to clipboard.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Double Click mouse event to listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195288/how-to-add-double-click-mouse-event-to-listbox)

Comment: Put your cursor in one of the blank fields in the second column of that grid and press `<enter>`.  That will create the event, wire it up, and put your in the code behind for the event.  While you are at it, take a before and after copy of the `.designer.cs` file and diff them.  It's interesting to see what _Mr. Wizard_ does for you

Comment: The link you posted in the comment is for **Windows Forms**, not **ASP.NET WebControls** - those are two very different technologies

Comment: thanks UnholySheep , I will try the solution mentioned in the link

Comment: thank you both, this worked for me if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "move")
        {
            if (ListBox5.SelectedItem.ToString().Length > 0)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetText(ListBox5.SelectedItem.ToString()));
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
            }
        }
        ListBox5.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(ListBox5, "move"));

Comment: @Kasi creating new threads in ASP.Net/ASP.Net-MVC is most likely totally wrong solution. In any case if you have answer it is much better to post it as answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so people can comment and vote on it (plus you can actually format it as code). If you believe the question is no longer interesting for future visitors - feel free to delete it (note that negative score on deleted questions counts for question ban as well - if you plan to continue using SO it usually better to improve the question rather than delete)

Answer (score -1):

[STAThread] worked for me on localhost but throw 502 error in real time, implemented ZeroClipBoard and it worked like charm on ListBox